# Why are atoms made up of only certain particles (protons, neutrons, electrons)?

Tags: particle-physics, electrons, nuclear-physics, atoms

Does it have to do with mass? I know particles like muons have the same charge as an electron, so why can't we have an atom that is made up of protons, neutrons, and muons?

Does the particle's mass affect how the strong force affects that particle? If so, that would mean it probably affects the structure of an atom and maybe the strong force would overcome the repulsion of the electromagnetic force between the negative charges if the particle was heavier.

And what's the point of the other elementary particles if they aren't part of atoms.

Comment: Why are atoms special in particular? Photons are pretty important too? And you can make muonic atoms...

Comment: The strong force only works on color charge, it ignores the mass of a particle, since gluons, which are massless are also confined through this force.

Answer (score 2):

To be constituents of ordinary matter, the particles have to be stable against decay on very long timescales. Bare protons and electrons are, and bare neutrons that are not stabilized by being tied up in a nucleus almost are (half-life of about 15 minutes). No other particles last long enough to make ordinary matter out of.

No one knows what the point is behind the experimental fact that we have three distinct families of fundamental particles (i.e., electrons AND muons AND tauons, plus their associated neutrinos, quarks & gluons).